# Creating a secure, web-based password management system with the ability to share data between users

Tags: ruby, security, encryption, openssl, public-key-encryption

I apologize in advance for the incoming **Wall-O-Text**. This is (at least, to me) a fairly complex issue that I've put quite a bit of thought into. You can read my question and also see a **test implementation** in Ruby (very hastily built, not database-backed, and probably very ugly) at [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/888975/cbccec57b74ad8d6bad14b41f70d3c784c33811a) if you are so inclined.

---

### Introduction

Imagine one was required to create a web-based password management system
(over SSL! :) with the following requirements:

1. Individual users sign in to the system using their own unique pass
    phrase.
2. This pass phrase should be enough to allow the user to use the system
    effectively (e.g. from a smartphone, etc.)--the point being that they
    should not have to keep a key file with them.
3. Users can store arbitrary-length bits of data in the system ("entries").
4. Entries are encrypted in the database in such a way that there is not
    enough information in the database or application alone to read the
    encrypted entries.
5. Users should be able to "share" entries with other users of the system
    so that the other user(s) can read the contents of the entry.

I'm no expert in cryptography. After thinking about it for a while, I came up
with the following.  **My question** is: is this implementation secure? Am I
missing something? If so, is the above spec even implementable? Or is this
overkill?

### Database

The database is set up as such:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  users                                                                       |
+---------+--------------+--------------+---------------+----------------------+
| salt    | pub_key      | enc_priv_key | priv_key_hmac |                      |
+---------+--------------+--------------+---------------+----------------------+
|  entries                                                                     |
+---------+--------------+--------------+---------------+----------+-----------+
| user_id | parent_entry | enc_sym_key  | sym_key_sig   | enc_data | data_hmac |
+---------+--------------+--------------+---------------+----------+-----------+
```

### Basic Use Cases

Let's imagine two users of the system, Alice and Bob.

Bob **signs up for the site**:

- Bob enters a password. This password is sent to the server (but not
  stored).
- The server generates a random salt and stores it in the `salt` field.
- The server generates the SHA-256 hash of Bob's password and salt.
- The server generates an RSA key pair. The public key is stored as plain
  text in the `pub_key` field. The private key is encrypted via AES-256
  using the hash generated from Bob's password and salt as the key and
  stored in the `enc_priv_key` field.
- The server generates a hash-based message authentication code for Bob's
  private key using Bob's password and salt as the key and stores this in
  the `priv_key_hmac` field.

Bob **stores an entry in the system**:

- Bob enters some data to be stored as an entry along with his password.
  This data is sent to the server.
- The server generates a key to be used as a key for AES-256 encryption.
- The server uses this key to encrypt the data and stores the result in
  the `enc_data` field.
- The server generates a hash-based message authentication code for the
  data using the generated key and stores this in the `data_hmac` field.
- The symmetric key used to encrypt the data is encrypted with Bob's public
  key and stored in the `enc_sym_key` field.
- The server uses Bob's private key to generate a signature for the
  symmetric key.

Bob **retrieves his stored entry**:

- Bob enters his password and the ID of the entry to retrieve.
- The server generates the SHA-256 hash of Bob's password and salt.
- Bob's encrypted private key is decrypted via AES-256 encryption using the
  hash.
- The server verifies that Bob's encrypted private key has not been
  tampered with by checking the HMAC in `priv_key_hmac`.
- The server decrypts the symmetric key stored in the `enc_sym_key` field
  using Bob's private key.
- The server verifies that the encrypted symmetric key has not been tampered
  with by verifying the signature in `sym_key_sign` using Bob's public key.
- The server decrypts the data using the symmetric key.
- The server verifies that the encrypted data has not been tampered with
  by verifying the HMAC stored in the `data_hmac` field.
- The server returns the decrypted data to Bob.

Bob **shares an entry with Alice**:

- Bob wants Alice to have access to an entry he owns. He enters his
  password and the ID of the entry to share.
- The data for the entry is decrypted using the method in "Bob retrieves
  his stored entry."
- A new entry is created for Alice in the same fashion as in "Bob stores
  an entry in the system," with the following exceptions:

  1. The entry's `parent_entry` is set to Bob's entry.
  2. The signature for the symmetric key is calculated using Bob's private
      key (since Alice's private key is not available to Bob).
  3. When Alice accesses this new entry, the existence of a non-null
      `parent_entry` causes the system to use Bob's public key to verify
      the signature (since his private key was used to create it).

Bob **changes the data in his shared entry**:

- Bob decides to change the data in the entry he shared with Alice. Bob
  indicates the entry ID to modify and the new data it should contain.
- The system overwrites the data created in "Bob stores an entry in the
  system."
- The system finds every entry with a `parent_entry` equal to the entry
  that was just modified, and for each one overwrites the data created in
  "Bob shares an entry with Alice."

### Analysis

Advantages:

- It is impossible to decrypt any data from the database without the
  password of the user that owns the data, as the private key necessary to
  decrypt the data is encrypted with the user's password, and that password
  (and it's hash) is not stored in the database.
- If a user wants to change their password, only their encrypted private
  key needs to be regenerated (decrypt the private key with the old
  password/hash, then re-encrypt it with the new password/hash).
- Shared entries are stored as actual separate records in the database,
  so there is no need to share a key between multiple users/groups of users.

Disadvantages/Problems (that I can think of):

- If a shared entry is modified, the system must re-encrypt every child
  entry; with a large number of users sharing data, this could potentially
  be computationally expensive.
- Shared entries depend on the parent user's public key for signature
  verification. If the user is deleted, or their key changes, the signatures
  are invalid.

Repeated from the introduction: my question is: is this implementation
secure? Am I missing something? If so, is the above spec even implementable?
Or is this overkill?

Thanks for sticking it out this long. I'm interested in your opinions! Am I on the right track, or a complete moron? YOU DECIDE! :)

Comment: From a user's point of view the idea here is that I can store passwords for various things that I use, online in this database, and if I want to give someone access to use one of my passwords I can do so? Or are these entries just arbitrary bits of text?

Comment: Yes, that is the basic idea. Parents could share passwords with children, IT managers could share passwords and configuration settings with departments, etc. I would like to be able to support uploaded files (or any generic data that is of an arbitrary length) which is why I didn't go public-key down the whole stack.

Comment: 1) Did you implement this? Any changes? 2) What happens if someone manages to change your client-side code and leak the user's password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No IV storage? I guess you could use AES-256-ECB, but that only lets users store 32 byte passwords, and you need to make sure that the generated private key is only ever used for *one* encryption. (Your current design seems safe in this respect, but if you want to allow passwords longer than 32 bytes, or *ever* think of making this key do double-duty, you'll need to store an IV for every encryption with it.)

I don't see the security value of `priv_key_hmac` and `data_hmac`; if either the private key or the encrypted data has been tampered with, then garbage output will result from decrypting with the private key or the symmetric key. Bob will surely be suspicious when he can't figure out how to type the `BEL` character. :) (Will humans ever see the output? A human will likely realize the returned password is incorrect without needing to be told. A computer couldn't tell the difference, so if automated systems will ever use the resulting passwords, then sure, keep the fields.)

There is no mechanism for "I forgot my password". Make sure your users know that there is no recovering their data if they forget their password. Users are coddled these days, and might expect to be coddled with your service too.

I see no mechanism for users to specify *which* entry Bob wants decrypted. You should store a name, or, as `ssh(1)` does in `known_hosts`, a *hashed* version of a name, for each entry. Storing a name directly would remove an SHA-256 operation, but a database compromise that reports the cleartext names of services that a user has accounts with might be every bit as damaging. (Perhaps an online escort service, or off-shore bank, or fight club.)

Comment: Great feedback! • In my research I had somehow skipped over IV's. There is a *possibility* that the AES-256 key used to encrypt data might be used for "double duty" in scenarios where an entry is shared with a group of users. OpenSSL seems to support generating a random IV, so I'll take a look at this. • I wasn't sure about the HMAC's. My concern is that someone with admin access to the database server could change the encrypted values to something that made sense, but is wrong. I'm not sure yet if automated systems will ever use the data in the entries--I'll give this some thought as well.

Comment: Definitely aware that forgotten passwords and the data created by the user who forgot it is lost forever. This whole idea came out of a need we had in my IT department, so we're good there. My primary concern is security, not usability--at least in this scenario. • My original idea was to have a `name` field for each entry, and then the data would be JSON-encoded so that freeform data could easily be stored and rendered on the client. If I hashed the names, how would I go about displaying them on the client's page upon login?

Comment: Ah, a couple more questions related to the IV: (1) I wouldn't need to store (or use?) an IV for the encrypted private key, right? As the symmetric key is only used once and the plain text being encrypted is guaranteed to be unique? (2) Is it fine to just store the IV unprotected next to the other data in the entry table or do I need to protect that value somehow? Thanks much for your insight.

Comment: @Brandon Tilley, hashing relies on the user to know which service they want to use. :) If your application is for internal corporate use then there is probably much less potential privacy risk due to the disclosure of the list of servers/services for which a user has accounts. Knowing that it is something your IT department wanted, I'll vote now for the side of usability: store the service names in plaintext.

Comment: @Brandon Tilley, Actually, including the service name as part of the HMAC data would prevent a DB admin from modifying service names, in case users have overlapping passwords. (If the service name isn't protected, and it is ever used by automated tools, a malicious admin could set up their own rogue service to sniff passwords after modifying legitimate entries to point to their rogue service. Probably not likely, but it sounds like you want everything covered.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to duplicate anything other than `enc_sym_key` when you share an entry with Alice - since the symmetric key is never re-used for more than one entry, you only need one copy of the encrypted data.

Comment: Good call; just encrypt the symmetric key with Alice's public key to share the data, yes?

Comment: @Brandon Tilley: Right (many existing systems work this way, for example S/MIME).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use certificates for sharing data between users? The use PKCS#12 certificates for holding the PEM and Private keys of users and the PEM per user or per site can sign and encrypt for data verification and security.

A scenario to illustrate.

Bob wants to share with Alice without Eve reading.

Alice gives Bob her public key. Bob adds Alice's public key to his keychain of trusted users. Bob then uses Alice's public key to encrypt a message while using his own PEM to sign the data. Of course this scenario requires that Alice already have a copy of Bob's public key to perform verification of the signature but you get the idea.

Also, why store a salt or iv? Both of these being stored along with at rest data will be accessible in the event of a db compromise.

Best practices...

1. Use a keyring for each user account for storage of others public keys/PEM certificates
2. Only use public key encryption for sharing information between accounts
3. Encrypt data with the users private key that is not to be shared between accounts
4. Do NOT use AES, RSA or any other reversible encryption for password storage
5. User specific salts should be used to further enhance hashing algorithm for password and should NOT be stored
6. Use of AES using a site wide password COULD be used for storage of at rest data to further improve security (but you would run into the problem you have outlined in the CONS section)